# WPF layout issue with nested StackPanel straying outside parent StackPanel

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

I have a horizontal StackPanel with an image and another StackPanel. The inner StackPanel is vertical with two TextBlocks both of which have TextWrapping set to Wrap.  However when the text gets wide the inner StackPanel increases in width so that the TextBlocks don't wrap.  The outer StackPanel is staying with the grid layout space it has been given. How can I make the inner StackPanel stay within the bounds of the outer StackPanel?

Here's the relevant section of XAML:

```
    <StackPanel Name="_imageAndNameStackPanel"
               Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
               Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="12,12,12,0">
        <Image Name="_applicationImage" Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" 
               Stretch="Fill" Height="64" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
        <StackPanel Name="_nameStackPanel">
            <TextBlock Name="_nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=AppName}" 
                 FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
            <TextBlock Name="_subtitleTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Subtitle"
                 FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,6,0,0" 
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably better off with a `DockPanel` instead of `StackPanel`.

```
<StackPanel Name="_imageAndNameStackPanel"
           Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
           Orientation="Horizontal"  Margin="12,12,12,0">
    <Image Name="_applicationImage" Source="{Binding Path=ImageUri}" 
           Stretch="Fill" Height="64" Width="64" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,12,0" />
    <DockPanel Name="_nameStackPanel">
        <TextBlock Name="_nameTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=AppName}" 
             FontSize="24" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
        <TextBlock Name="_subtitleTextBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Subtitle"
             FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,6,0,0" 
             TextWrapping="Wrap" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Lately I'm finding that 2 out of 3 times that I start with `StackPanel` I end up changing it to `DockPanel`.

But… are you *sure* that the outer `StackPanel` is not expanding beyond the bounds of its grid cell? You might want to make that one a `DockPanel` as well, with both the `Image` and the inner `DockPanel` having `DockPanel.Dock="Left"`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the outer stackpanel isn't growing. I can see its size in the designer when I select that panel in the XAML.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your inner StackPanel's width to the Parent StackPanel's width. Something like:

`{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type StackPanel}}, Path=Width}`

Comment: the outer StackPanel has a horizontal orientation, so it must be the width of the outer StackPanel minus the width of the Image.

Answer (score -1):

Give your inner stackpanel or textblock's a fixed width.

Comment: I would like the TextBlocks to size with the overall width of the dialog box they are in. As a fallback, I'll probably wind up doing that. I was hoping for something a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Then I would change both of your stackpanels to dock panels as suggested by Jay (or use a single grid, 2 columns by 3 rows: one column for your image spanning three rows, then in the second column each row gets one of your textblocks except for the bottom row is empty (assuming that's the look you're going for)).